# Can I use pyusb to communicate with my USB device without installing extra driver

Tags: driver, libusb, pyusb

I want to develop a portable USB device. And now I want to communicate with this device by using Pyusb. I use python 2.7 under windows 7, and I install a backend (I choose libusb-win32) which will install its own driver. I am new to USB and pyusb, so I wonder if there is no driver, can I communicate with this device and can this device communicate with a clean PC.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already figured this out in the meantime, but the answer is "yes": Using libusb / PyUSB you can interact with a USB device without the need for a dedicated driver. You'll have to perform any protocol handling in user-space, though.

Comment: Do you need always need install the inf file generated by libusb for each device or is there a better way?

Comment: If not outdated, could you please add a link how to "perform any protocol handling in users-space"? But I'm sure somebody has done this before somewhere, somehow.